# Iterate multiple soil fields through Calculate Field

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, iteration, soil

I understand this can easily be done manually using Calculate Field, however I'm looking to automate this process using ModelBuilder as it is a requirement of the current module.

I have 7 Weather columns in my soils feature class table, X Dry, Dry, Moist, Wet, X Wet, Frozen & X Frozen. The values of these fields are either GO, Restricted, Severely Restricted or Unknown. However they have purposely been assigned different values, so when being converted from a polygon to a raster Go should = 0, R = 1, SR + Unk = 2, but they don't all read like that when making it a Raster, giving me false outputs on my CCM analysis. I need to pre-engineer the soils data before bringing it into a raster calculator.

I have run a Calculate Field using Python:

```
Reclass(!WET_GO!)

def Reclass(field):
  if field =='GO':
    return 0
  elif field == 'R':
    return 1
  elif field == 'SR':
    return 2
  elif field == 'UNK':
    return 2
```

This gives me my desired output (see attached image) however it will only run for the one Field. I have tried using ArcGIS Pro's Iterate functions but I cant seem to figure out how to get it to run for all 7 of the weather conditions without adding 7 field calculators to my model which I do not want to do.

Currently it is just replacing the values in the attribute table but if it is easier new fields can be added to populate the 0/1/2 values in.

[image: Soils Attribute Table]

Answer (score 1):

No Python code is required and this can be done in model builder in ArcPro using the [Fields Iterator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-fields.htm). You need to be using at least ArcPro 2.6; earlier versions do not have this iterator.

The model is simply this:

[image: Model]

The iterator filters the required fields and the calculate field tool is set up as is:

[image: Calculate Field]

Note: I had renamed the output of the iterator to "myField", the default name is a generic "Value", just makes things clearer as to what the object is.

*Note: be aware such a model could not be shared and used in ArcMap as the iterator does not exist in ArcMap*

Comment: Oh I didnt know it existed, nice!

Comment: @BERA there is also the [Layers Iterator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-layers.htm) that has crept in since ArcPro 2.7 but that seems flaky as the only time I tried to use it, it didn't work, so I gave up and went the Python way.  :)

Comment: Thankyou! sorry for the late reply, we moved over to MCA but I'm back on CCM now. Your images made perfect sense and I understand the concept of how it works, however when I run the calculate field it only seems to run 1 of the "iterate Fields" the one that is displayed in value, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't attach an image to the comment so I've posted it here instead
[image: This is the picture of my current model]

Comment: I would start with the [nullable error](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/160001-170000/tool-errors-and-warnings-160126-160150-160145.htm) and make sure that field is nullable. You might have to create a new featureclass making sure that property is nullable.

Comment: I think that dataset was just shite tbh, on my summative now and I did exactly the same process and it worked first time no issues whatsoever, and yeah I did try changing it to allow null values but everything about the data was locked, I couldn't change anything. Figured out the issue with it only running one field calculator, I just needed to add a precondition to the iterator, but thankyou for all the help, much appreciated!!

Comment: Yes a weirdness of model builder is that it will run tools in the order they are added to the model canvas so setting the precondition is a way of enforcing order of sequence.